Why is RocksDB Memtable exceeding its memory limit?
We are using Kafka Streams and Kafka and we are having an Out of Memory issue with one of our applications because the non-jvm memory is exceeding its limit.
On further investigation, we can observe that one of the rocksdb memtables exceeds 300MB. The rocksdb is managed by Kafka Streams.
This happens even though we are setting the total memtable size limit to 300MB with this custom rocksdb configuration:
        BlockBasedTableConfig tableConfig = (BlockBasedTableConfig) options.tableFormatConfig();

        long cacheCapacity = getCacheCapacity(storeName);
        Cache cache = new LRUCache(cacheCapacity);

        long memtableMemory = getMemtableMemory(storeName);
        WriteBufferManager writeBufferManager = new WriteBufferManager(memtableMemory, cache);

        tableConfig.setBlockCache(cache);
        tableConfig.setCacheIndexAndFilterBlocks(true);

        tableConfig.setCacheIndexAndFilterBlocksWithHighPriority(true);
        tableConfig.setPinTopLevelIndexAndFilter(true);

        options.setWriteBufferManager(writeBufferManager);

Can someone help? Is this an issue with Kafka Streams or with our configuration?
Here is the Write Buffer Manager documentation from RocksDB
And here is the recommendations for Rocksdb memory management by Confluent
We tried setting the write buffer manager's memory and that should limit the total memtable memory usage but that didn't work.

can you make clear what exactly your problem is? I don't get it....

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I believe it's setPinTopLevelIndexAndFilter(true) -- pinning is stricter than the memory limit from my understanding, and thus if index and filter blocks take more than your 300MB limit, the limit would be exceeded. -- In general, size of index/filter blocks is lower than overall data size and thus pinning makes sense and we recommend it. But yes, you need enough memory to fix it in when pinning.
